# Unhandled kernel version error when trying to install laptop-mode-tools

Tags: 11.10

Hi I'm getting this error after installing laptop-mode-tools in Oneiric Ocelot when its trying to run for the first time:

```
Unhandled kernel version: 3.0 ('uname -r' = 3.0.0-12-generic)
```

So my laptop-mode-tools is 1.57-1ubuntu1, and I saw in the launchpad that Ubuntu team is preparing 1.58-3ubuntu1 that contains support for kernel 3.0.

However, I don't find 1.58-3ubuntu1 in apt-cache showpkg laptop-mode-tools (only 1.57 is listed) so I can't upgrade my laptop-mode-tools.

I tried adding kernel PPA into my repository cache and apt-get update, and in apt-cache showpkg linux-headers only 3.0.0.12-generic is showing up. So I can't downgrade my kernel either.

I want laptop-mode-tools to work with Oneiric since I'm on laptop, what do you guys suggest me to do ? I'm an absolute beginner so please be easy on your answer. I can work with packages, but not with patching/compiling, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the suggestion in this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/laptop-mode-tools/+bug/801623) I added kernel version in laptop-mode-tools script. So you should add "3.0");; to the file /usr/sbin/laptop_mode about line 506 so it reads as follows:

```
case "$KLEVEL" in
 "2.4" ) ;;
 "2.6" ) ;;
 "3.0" ) ;;
 *)
  log "ERR" "Unhandled kernel version: $KLEVEL ('uname -r' = '$(uname -r)')" >&2
  exit 1
  ;;
```

If you want to avoid laptop-mode-tools completely you may add the following script in `/etc/pm/power.d/` and name it `powersave`. It does something similar to laptop-mode. You may need to tweak the script according to you hardware.

```
#!/bin/sh
# A script to enable laptop power saving features for #! & Debian GNU+linux.
# http://crunchbanglinux.org/forums/topic/11954

# List of modules to unload, space seperated. Edit depending on your hardware and preferences.
modlist="uvcvideo"
# Bus list for runtime pm. Probably shouldn't touch this.
buslist="pci spi i2c"

case "$1" in
    true)
    # Enable some power saving settings while on battery
       # Enable laptop mode
        echo 5 > /proc/sys/vm/laptop_mode
       # Less VM disk activity. Suggested by powertop
        echo 1500 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs
       # Intel power saving
        echo Y > /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save_controller
        echo 1 > /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save
       # Set backlight brightness to 50%
        echo 3 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
       # USB powersaving
        for i in /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/autosuspend; do
            echo 1 > $i
        done
       # SATA power saving
        for i in /sys/class/scsi_host/host*/link_power_management_policy; do
            echo min_power > $i
        done
       # Disable hardware modules to save power
        for mod in $modlist; do
            grep $mod /proc/modules >/dev/null || continue
            modprobe -r $mod 2>/dev/null
        done
       # Enable runtime power management. Suggested by powertop.
        for bus in $buslist; do
            for i in /sys/bus/$bus/devices/*/power/control; do
                echo auto > $i
            done
        done
    ;;
    false)
       #Return settings to default on AC power
        echo 0 > /proc/sys/vm/laptop_mode
        echo 500 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs
        echo N > /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save_controller
        echo 0 > /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save
        echo 12 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
        for i in /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/autosuspend; do
            echo 2 > $i
        done
        for i in /sys/class/scsi_host/host*/link_power_management_policy
            do echo max_performance > $i
        done
        for mod in $modlist; do
            if ! lsmod | grep $mod; then
                modprobe $mod 2>/dev/null
            fi
        done
        for bus in $buslist; do
            for i in /sys/bus/$bus/devices/*/power/control; do
                echo on > $i
            done
        done
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

[Source](http://crunchbanglinux.org/forums/post/110148/#p110148)

OR although I havenot used it, many have recommended [jupiter applet](http://www.jupiterapplet.org/) for power saving. You can install it from ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jupiter
```

[Source](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/jupiter-applet-finally-available-for.html)

Comment: Ah.. cool! I followed your first suggestion and it works. Thanks!